# Dell xps15 touch pad makes launcher stuck

Tags: launcher, touchpad

Randomly using the touch pad my launcher is on auto hide, but it glitches out and permanently shows the launcher until I restart. When it happens, the search of unity flickers in a glitch way. The opacity also turns off too.

Is there any way to fix this? I've been using a usb mouse to avoid this.